# JavaScript - Condição de Parada

Tags: javascript

Quero pedir vários nomes digitados via prompt, e ter alguma condição de parada, pensei nessa condição sendo um número, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
let nomes = []
let dado = ""

console.log(typeof(dado))
while(dado == String){
    dado = prompt("Digite um nome para continuar o programa, ou digite o número 0 para encerra-lo.")
    if(typeof(dado) == String) nomes.push(dado)
    if(dado == 0) parseInt(dado)
}

for(i = nomes.length; i == 0; i--){
    console.log(nomes[i])
}
```

Comment: `if(dado == 0) break`

Comment: Mas por que precisaria de condição de parada se o próprio `prompt` tem a função `cancelar`?
Não seria melhor mudar o texto? `Digite um nome para continuar o programa, ou clique em cancelar para encerra-lo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas:

1. `String` é uma função, ao compara-lá com a variável `dado` sempre retornará `false`
2. O retorno da expressão `typeof <variavel>` será uma string, e se o tipo for string será `"string"` (tudo em minúsculo)
3. Não tem o porquê de avaliar o tipo retornado pela função `prompt`, semrpe será uma string, mesmo que digite um número, por exemplo, ao digitar 0, retornará `"0"`
4. A não ser que o array de nomes esteja vazio seu loop `for` nunca será executado, da forma como quer a condição deveria ser `i != 0`

```js
let nomes = []
let dado = ''

// Se for digitado '0', o loop é encerrado
while(dado !== '0') {
    dado = prompt('Digite um nome para continuar o programa, ou digite o número 0 para encerra-lo.')

    // Se não for digitado '0' adiciona aos nomes
    if (dado !== '0') nomes.push(dado)
}

// Uma sintaxe diferente para fazer o loop
for (const nome of nomes) console.log(nome)
```

Comment: Gostei da solução, mas ifs e fors inline sem chaves dificulta o entendimento, mesmo o JS permitindo isto.

Comment: É questão de ponto de vista, considerando que na pergunta usa eles, o usuário sabe como funciona